# Odoo QWeb Put Div in Right Place

Tags: xml, odoo, qweb

I have a simple div

```
<div>
    <span>My City, 25 Jan 2022</span><br/>
    <span>My Company, Bla Bla Bla</span><br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <strong><center>My Name</center></strong>
</div>
```

I want to place that div in the right place of the page, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `row` and `text-right` class.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md text-md-right">
        <span class="text-right">Some text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this answer could be helpful for you.